# Can intern test JavaScript dependent on HTML markup?

Tags: intern

I'd like to be able to test a widget in the same way that Dojo's DOH could.
An example of this is for example dijit tests e.g. https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/tests/Fieldset.html

DOH runs in the browser and can test if a declarative widget has been created, test properties on the widget etc

Is this possible with intern using runner.js or would I have to use webdriver and use an execute eval e.g. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#POST_/session/:sessionId/execute (which I really don't want to do)

Any examples I've seen on this rely on programatically creating the markup, using eval wouldn't achieve what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

I would use PhantomJS for this. It looks like they have documentation for that here: https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Intern-with-PhantomJS